# Simplifying $\max_{\|w\|^2\le 1} \|Aw\|^2 - \|Bw \|^2$

Tags: calculus, linear-algebra, matrices, vector-spaces, eigenvalues-eigenvectors

Is it true that
\begin{align}
\max_{\|w\|^2\le 1} \|Aw\|^2 - \|B w\|^2 &= \sigma_{\max} ( A^*A - B^*B),
\end{align}
where $\sigma_{\max}$ is the maximal singular value of its argument and $A^*$ is the conjugate transpose of matrix $A$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No. Consider e.g. $A=0$ and $B=I$. However, we do have
\begin{aligned}
\max_{\|w\|^2\le1}\left(\|Aw\|^2-\|Bw\|^2\right)
&=\max_{\|w\|\le1}w^\ast(A^\ast A-B^\ast B)w\\
&=\lambda_\max(A^\ast A-B^\ast B)
\end{aligned}
and
\begin{aligned}
\max_{\|w\|^2\le1}\left|\|Aw\|^2-\|Bw\|^2\right|
&=\max_{\|w\|\le1}\left|w^\ast(A^\ast A-B^\ast B)w\right|\\
&=\rho(A^\ast A-B^\ast B)\\
&=\sigma_\max(A^\ast A-B^\ast B).
\end{aligned}

Comment: What is $\rho$ in  your second derivation?

Comment: @Morad Spectral radius.